# Hiberate - Different ways of writing to a database

Tags: java, hibernate

I have been asked a question by a perspective employer, that I need to investigate and have an answer ready for the next phone interview.

They know that I have no Hibernate experience, and they have asked me the following:
Describe more than one way to write to a database using Hibernate.

Fair enough, I've been reading and Googling like there's no tomorrow, and I've found examples like the following one that illustrates how to update a row in a table:

`Query query = session.createQuery("update Stock set stockName = :stockName" +
                    " where stockCode = :stockCode");
query.setParameter("stockName", "DIALOG1");
query.setParameter("stockCode", "7277");
int result = query.executeUpdate();`

That makes sense to me, and I now have a high level understanding of how HQL works, using class names and properties, rather than table names and columns.

But what do they mean by another way of writing to a database? Does any one have any idea as to what feature of Hibernate they are trying to get me to find?

Comment: pretty unclear to me.  maybe INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/ALTER ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you can save directly an instance of an Entity:

```
Stock stock = new Stock();
session.save(stock);
```

But you can also execute native SQL sentence:

```
session.createSQLQuery("insert into stock_table ...").executeUpdate();
```

Comment: SqlQuery does not update the current session or caches. Use with caution.